# Why pain and suffering?

Tags: philosophy, bhagavad-gita, bhagavata-purana, upanishads

We see a lot of conflicts, accidents, diseases, poverty, pain and suffering around us in our day to day life.

I often wonder why god created so much misery and so little goodness.

What is His plan in all this (happiness & suffering) at the end?

Comment: Do you blame the government for making roads if an accident takes place on the road? God creates the infrastructure, what we do with it is up to us. And what do you mean by little goodness. There is lot of goodness happening daily, but it is not interesting so you don't see on the news that 10 lakh people went to a temple today, or 1 crore people took care of their parents and children etc.

Comment: What do you mean by the word " this" in the last sentence. Do you mean his plan in all the happenings in the world  OR Do you mean by Pain & suffering.IMO its unclear what exactly you want to know. You can edit the question anytime.

Comment: Conflicts what you mention all because of people who around you, There is No pain No gain. As a Human we need all emotions if we have all then only you can feel Happy, Love and caring etc. God is a creator/Destroyer, we all can decide how we want to be. Until unless we are happy with what we have there is no Pain. So be Happy (Build positivity) and make others happy it will reduce most of all so called Conflicts. Here I haven't understand your Tag, I think you have to edit with suitable one.

Comment: Same query by the Buddha, and  the same answer today.

Answer (score 3):

**Why pain & sufferings?-**
It has been explained in Shiva Rahasya Chapter 2.

> 25. Time  is  eternal and restrains everything from  within.  Hence, Time  is  One  with the Supreme All-Knowing Lord.   Indeed, Infinite Time is Eternal  Truth Itself.   It creates  and destroys  the finite time known to unawakened man.  He who realises the power of Unending Time, for him limited time comes to an end.  He attains Eternal Life.
> 26. But he  who is pray  to  finite time,  knows not  the Limitless.  He is bound to  the limited things of limited life.  Thinking,  What is now being  perceived by  me: this Mind, this Body, these Possessions; they belong to me, they  are  part of  me, I am  these and  nothing else.  By  this way of thinking, the unenlightened Ego Mind leads the Soul  to identify  himself  with these constituents of Material Reality.
> 27. O  you  who are most wise! know that the Universe is a well-ordered Unity of interdependent forms.  All things therein,  rocks, plants, fish, birds and beasts dwell in harmony with each other and according to My  World-Supporting  Law. **Of all creatures, ignorant  men alone act not by  My Command.**
> 28. For they  are possessed by a vain  Ego: not content with what I Myself allotted them, they yearn to be  something else.  Moreover, they  lift  themselves in pride above others and  give themselves to works that are hateful and wrong.
> 29. **Possessed by  a defective Ego  they break the Sacred Bond of  Unity  and go to the Abode of Discord where Sin is their God and sorrow their lot**.  Therefore, well do the wise ones know that Ego is man's greatest foe.
> 30. Thus, through association with the Ego, the deluded Sense of I, the Soul who is Pure  Spirit comes to forget his true identity and succumbs to the conviction that he is non-Spirit.
> 31. Having  forgotten that he himself is Pure  and Perfect, Self-Shining Light, the Soul deems himself to be as dull and lacklustre as the material substance he identifies with. **In this dull condition, having once  shined like  a Great Star  in the midst of the Infinite Vault of Consciousness, he becomes dependent upon outer, physical light.**
> 32. Having once soared like an Eagle in the Radiant Sky  of Spiritual Reality, **he now stands helpless upon the hard ground of physical existence, enveloped in gloom.**
> 33. Due to this blind darkness that  separates  them  from  the  Light of Spirit, **the heart  of unEnlightened Souls is ever-restless, tormented and suffers all kinds of pain**.

**Summary-** Identifying ourselves with something which we're not **is the ultimate reason of sufferings.**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The explanation for pain and suffering is that Jivas live in duality where there is both pain and pleasure, both happiness and misery. You can't have only pleasure and no pain since this world is in a state of duality. Only in the non-dual state is there no such pairing.

> Brahman is beyond vidya and avidya, knowledge and ignorance. It is
>   beyond maya, the illusion of duality.  The world consists of the
>   illusory duality of knowledge and ignorance. It contains of knowledge
>   and devotion, and also attachment to 'lust and greed'; righteousness
>   and unrighteousness; good and evil. But Brahman is unattached to
>   these. Good and evil apply to the jiva, the individual soul, as do
>   righteousness and unrighteousness; but Brahman is not at all
>   unaffected by them.  One man may read the Bhagavata by the light of
>   the lamp, and another may commit a forgery by that very light; but
>   that lamp is unaffected. The sun sheds its light on the wicked as well
>   as on the virtuous.  **You may then ask, 'How, then can one explain
>   misery, and sin and unhappiness?' The answer is that these apply to
>   the jiva.** Brahman is unaffected by them. There is poison in a snake;
>   but though others may die if bitten by it, the snake itself is not
>   affected by the poison.

The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna